# How to implement slide in/out view with controls in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, viewcontroller, dialog

I am new to windows phone (WP7) and to me it looks like everything on WP7 is about pages. I want a small window to pop up from the bottom of a page while staying on the same page. The small window will have some controls (like slider, list etc.). It should not behave like a modal dialog box though, i.e. the rest of the page (which is not covered by the small window) should still be active and user should be able to do something there. And I want to have a separate C# class which will handle the events from the controls on the small window.

This is very easy on iPhone, using view controllers, is there something similar on windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that it would make sense to make your "pop up" part of the page with the content it is intended to manipulate content on that page. If you want to encapsulate the functionality of the "pop up" you could make it a UserControl. If you went this route then animating it to slide onto the screen will be straightforward.

Windows Phone 7 typically uses an MVVM model compared to iPhone's MVC one for app structure. The direct comparison therefore isn't appropriate. WP7 also uses a very different design language to that of the iPhone and so a straight port of application design and layout is also unlikely to create a great experience on WP7.

I'd recommend taking some time to understanding the differences in the platforms and how your existing design would be best suited to recreation on WP7. Not only will this help you create a better experience on WP7 but enable to see if this your question actually relates to something you should be doing or not.

Answer (score 0):

This very much sounds like something that goes against the nature of the platform, and the general design guidelines.

If you're providing some available configuration options to the user, you should do it on a separate page, so the user can change the settings there, approve it, and then be navigated back to the previous page.

However, if you really want to, you're talking about displaying a `UserControl` inside a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). But it wouldn't be a very good user experience, and confuse most users, as it doesn't follow the same look&feel as the rest of the platform.

Comment: Thanks Claus. I need this because I have some objects on the main page and there could be quite a few different categories of configuration options (mostly with sliders) which can change the look and feel of the objects on the main page real time (when the slider moves). Let me try to understand the Popup stuff.